# Where can I put the `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` flag?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use the `1.4.21-2` version of kotlin which is a recent version that has a fix that allows you to use Compose + Kotlin serialization without the build hanging. This is all great, however, the Compose compiler does not know about it and gives the following (rather unhelpful) error:

> e: This version (1.0.0-alpha09) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.4.21 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.4.21-2 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

I would love to provide that suppression flag, however I don't know where to put it... I've spent about an hour trying to put it in random places in my gradle files, for example in `composeOptions`, but no luck. I also tried all the google-fu I know, but nobody seems to have actually used this and wrote anything about it.

Any ideas how to get out of that predicament?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a command line argument.

See this [example in a kts file here](https://github.com/IVIanuu/injekt/blob/d572f48f9a1ec8d7053ef9255d0b38473a944bca/build.gradle.kts#L73-L75)

```
-P plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true
```

Answer (score 35):

I have the same problem with message:

```
e: This version (1.0.0-alpha11) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.4.21-2 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.4.21 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).
```

Adding compiler args solved my problem:

```
"-P", "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true"
```

You can add it to all `KotlinCompile` tasks. In app level Gradle it looks like the following:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-Xallow-jvm-ir-dependencies",
                "-P",
                "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

if you are using KTS,

```kotlin
android {
    ...

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        useIR = true

        freeCompilerArgs += listOf(
            "-P",
            "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true"
        )

    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get compose 1.1.1 to work with kotlin 1.6.20.  Compose only works with 1.6.10 without suppressing this version check.  If I use the supplied code, I have to remove useIR = true because now it is declared as val instead of var.  You can't change it.  After removing the useIR line, I get an error stating NoSuchMethodError "e: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrSetFieldImpl".  Anybody else having this issue?

Answer (score 13):

For multi-module projects add the suppression flag to project's root-level `build.gradle` inside `allprojects {}` section:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Suppress Compose Kotlin compiler compatibility warning
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    "-P",
                    "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A better solution is to add a `composeOptions` section to your `:app` module `build.gradle` file.

```
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.3.2"
    }
```

This is what is recommended in the [Android Compose Kotlin Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)

Comment: Wow, this helped me, but with another version 1.3.1, thank you!!

Comment: yes working and use kotlin version 1.7.20

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Gradle Grovy script (build.gradle),

```
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        useIR = true

        freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-P",
                "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me
`Could not set unknown property 'useIR' for object of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptionsImpl.`
If I remove that, I get: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.TypeTranslatorImpl.<init>(org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.ReferenceSymbolTable, org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.LanguageVersionSettings, org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.ModuleDescriptor, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0, boolean, org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.StubGeneratorExtensions, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)'`

Comment: Seems like Compose really needs that Kotlin version then.

Answer (score 1):

You can also always simply downgrade the Kotlin Gradle Plugin to the version it states, i.e:

```kotlin
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    val compose_version by extra("1.0.0-beta07")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-beta02")
        
        // This is the line you want to change to the needed version
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32")
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the one that I wanted, perfect and elegant, thanks!